# How to tackle when the status of an webelement changes from initial value "xxx" to changed value "yyy" after the page refresh with selenium wait?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

This is what i have tried with no luck,
Not sure where i am going wrong?

```
   if (("xxx").equals(messageStatus)) {      
   FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver> (driver)            
                .withTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                  
                .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)            
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);              

  wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {      
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver webDriver) {            
           String messageStatus =
  MessageLogPage.messageStatus.getText();            
                if (messageStatus.equals("yyy")){              
                    MessageLogPage.receivedPresentation.click();            
                }      
                    return null;          
                 }                
        });
```

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be that if your page truly refreshes, the old reference to `MessageLogPage.messageStatus` becomes invalid. I.e. it's not only that messageStatus text changes, but the element instance itself does too.

So I would change the algorithm to get the element every time before getting its text. Also you should not click inside wait, do it after:

```
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {      
           @Override public WebElement apply(WebDriver webDriver) {            
               try {
                   WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.<...>); // however you can locate MessageLogPage.messageStatus
                   if(element.getText().equals("yyy")) {
                       return element;
                   }      
                }
                catch(Exception e) { } // keep going (retun null)
                return null;                
        });
```

`wait.until` will call this function multiple times until return value is not null or timeout has expired, in which case it will throw an exception. So next line after `wait.until`, can be the click:

```
 wait.until(...); // above code
 MessageLogPage.receivedPresentation.click(); // we are here only if wait.until did not throw the exception
```

Although it could be that `MessageLogPage.receivedPresentation` may also be invalid if page refreshed.

You can even further simplify it by returning `Boolean`, since you don't really care about this element after you found it:

```
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {      
           @Override public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {            
               try {
                   WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.<...>); // however you can locate MessageLogPage.messageStatus
                   return element.getText().equals("yyy");
               }
               catch(Exception e) { } // keep going (return false)
               return false;          
        });
```